# Secure account creation on a server after using Facebook LoginButton in a mobile app

Tags: android, facebook, api, security

I would like to create an app in which there is a mobile (Android) client which uses REST API from the server. A user has to login with Facebook account (using Facebook SDK's LoginButton); on success this should create a user account on the server at the first log in.

I've already read a lot of tutorials about how to secure HTTP API using SSL and access tokens, but there is one point which I don't get. The flow should look like this:

1. a user log in on the Android app with the Facebook LoginButton
2. in the Android app I receive an access token on successful log in which I can push to the server
3. I can validate this access token against Graph API
4. if validation in 3. is succesful I can create a user account on the server
5. all other calls to my server API can be secured with received access token or other token which would be created by me

but what about the 2. point? I have to expose API call which takes an access token and creates an account. This API call won't be secured, so if someone calls it with stolen/properly fabricated access token, then I will create an account which shouldn't exist. How to solve this? Do I have to assume that if my create account API is called with an access token which is valid (because I validate it in 3.) then everything is ok? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, never trust the client. Always validate all client input again on the server.

In your case, you're validation of the token on the server in Step 3 should include comparing the result from Graph API with the result from decrypting the user info from the token. If both match, then proceed.

There are several code examples on [Facebook website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login) on how to do this correctly. They are available in several server languages (e.g. PHP) so I recommend reviewing them.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check how to validate access tokens. But still I wonder what is the probability that Graph API will validate an access token which is stolen/procured.
Another thing: it is a good idea to store an access token on the client and use it in every request? Or should I generate my own token on account creation and send it back to the client? Or maybe even different approach?

Comment: Your first question: It is possible. The Graph API cannot tell if the token was stolen or not. A stolen token is a valid token. And as long as the user hasn't logged out, the token will stay valid. On mobile devices, most users almost never log out. In this case, the token will expire and get replaced with a new token automatically by the Facebook app. I don't remember how long it takes for the token to expire, but I think it was like a day or two. Now, how likely is it for a token to be stolen? Well, that depends on how secure are all the apps on the users device that are using the token.

Comment: Your second question: The Facebook link in my answer, answers all those questions. There are two different types of token, so make sure you don't mix them up.

Comment: I am starting to get confused... By two different types of token what do you mean? Tokens generated by my server and token generated by Facebook? Two different types of tokens generated by Facebook? In particular: I see this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#codeflow but I don't understand this sentence. Do they mean short-lived tokens generated by me or by Facebook?

Comment: The word "two" was a typo. I meant to say "There are different types of tokens". There are 4 types, and I'm talking about Facebook tokens not yours, because I have no idea about the design of your app. Read [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) for details about those 4 types of tokens. Then scroll down to the **Short-Term and Long-Term Tokens** title and read it to answer your question. But the short answer is: they only talk about tokens generated by Facebook, not you app.